# Does VSTS automatically convert a Basic level subscription to Visual Studio subscription?

Tags: azure-devops

I want to add a new user to VSTS who doesn't have a Visual Studio subscription as of now. But, after a few days, the user will be assigned a subscription. At that time, is the basic subscription automatically converted to Visual Studio subscription?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is what will happen.  Microsoft keeps track of licensing of all the users registered in your account and will update this page accordingly.